# WPF treeview with heirarchical databinding using multiple data sources

Tags: wpf, xaml, ironpython

I have this wpf structure:

```
 <TreeView x:Name="tree" ItemsSource="{Binding MainDirectory}"> 
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding _directory}">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding _name}" >
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

 </TreeView>
```

My directories display great but my _directory property also have a _file property that I want to display inside the treeview. Whenever I try to add another treeviewitem though WPF tells me that the visual tree is set more than once. Is there any way I can achieve this. Thank you

Comment: `_directory` & `_name` look like fields (probably private). Binding may not be able to recognize the same unless they are public properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tree" ItemsSource="{Binding MainDirectory}"> 
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding _directory}">
                         <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                              <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding _file}">
                                   <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding _name}" />
                              </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                         </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding _name}" >
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

 </TreeView>
```